# How should I catch exceptions in a decorator function that can raise, if the decorator function is in a library I can't modify?

Tags: python, sockets, google-app-engine, decorator, statsd

I'm working the [python statsd library](http://statsd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) on Google App Engine (GAE).  Unfortunately, GAE can raise `ApplicationError: 4 Unknown error.` from time to time when using sockets.  The error is an `apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError`.

The statsd client is already setup to catch `socket.error`, but not the `ApplicationError` that sockets can raise on GAE.

I'm specifically working with `timer`, which returns an instance of `Timer`:
https://github.com/jsocol/pystatsd/blob/master/statsd/client.py#L13

The `__call__` method of `Timer` allows it to be used as a decorator, like so:

```
from statsd import StatsClient

statsd = StatsClient()

@statsd.timer('myfunc')
def myfunc(a, b):
    """Calculate the most complicated thing a and b can do."""
```

I don't have easy ability to modify the `Timer.__call__` method itself to simply also catch `ApplicationError`.

How should I write a wrapper or additional decorator that still allows clean decoration like `@my_timer_wrapper('statsd_timer_name')` but which catches additional exceptions that may occur in the wrapped/decorated `timer` method?

This is in a foundation module in my codebase that will be used in many places (wherever we want to time something).  So although [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17033293/635032) might work, I really want to avoid forcing all uses of `@statsclient.timer` in my codebase to themselves be defined within `try-except` blocks.

I'm thinking of doing something like the following:

```
def my_timer_wrapper(wrapped_func, *args, **kwargs):
  @functools.wraps(wrapped_func)
  class Wat(object):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      timer_instance = stats_client.timer(*args, **kwargs)
      try:
        return timer_instance.__call__(wrapped_func)(*args, **kwargs)
      except Exception:
        logger.warning("Caught exception", exc_info=True)
        def foo():
          pass
        return foo

  return Wat()
```

which would then be used like:

```
@my_timer_wrapper('stastd_timer_name')
def timed_func():
  do_work()
```

Is there a better or more pythonic way?

Comment: Looks like that class can be used as a context manager instead, that would be easier to wrap in a try/except.

Comment: You could just monkey patch statsd. Perform the patching in appengine_config.py so it only needs to be performed once in you codebase.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a case for an "as straightforward as possible" 
new decorator adding an extra try/except around your timer decorator.

The only matter being that decorators that take parameters needing
2 levels of nested functions to be defined, almost always makes them 
look complicated, even when they are not:

```
from functools import wraps

def  shielded_timer(statsd, 
                    exceptions=(apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError),
                    name=None):

    def decorator(func):
        timer_decorator = statsd.timer(name or func.__name__)
        new_func = timer_decorator(func)
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            try:
                return new_func(*args, **kw)
            except BaseException as error:
                if isinstance (error, exceptions):
                    # Expected error (ApplicationError by default) ocurred
                    pass
                else:
                    raise
        return wrapper
    return decorator



#####################
statsd = StatsClient()
@shielded_timer(statsd)
def my_func(a,b):
    ...
```

As you can see it is easy enough to even include extra niceties - in this case I've made the wanted exceptions configurable at decoration time, and optionally, it uses the name of the decorated function automatically in the
call to statsd.timer.